What problems can I have with spawning a set of new threads from Servlet and what alternatives exist?
For simplicity, I will omit some details and try to highlight the main point:
I have a servlet that consumes users' requests, when a user sends a request I need to gather data from many endpoints. One user can have data from many sources, so, I need to get all data from all sources and respond to them to the user. To get data from one endpoint I need to call a HTTP URL. It takes a significant count of time. Let's say from 1 second to 20 minutes.
So, now, for example, we have a user Jonh and he has 3 sources with documents. He requests his documents from my servlet and I start to gather documents. Sours by source I request data and collect it in a list, then I respond it to John. Obviously, John can wait for a while and he will be angry. Here is an example:
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

@RestController
public class SearchDocumentsController {

    @GetMapping("/search/{userId}")
    public List<String> searchDocuments(@PathVariable String userId) {
        List<String> connections = getUserConnections(userId);
        List<String> documents = syncDocuments(userId, connections);
        return documents;
    }

    // Simulate a method that retrieves user connections
    private List<String> getUserConnections(String userId) {
        return List.of("one", "two", "three");
    }

    // This method is the one that takes a long time to execute
    public List<String> syncDocuments(String userId, List<String> connections) {
        List<String> documents = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String connection : connections) {
            List<String> documentsFromOneConnection = searchInDataSource(userId, connection);
            documents.addAll(documentsFromOneConnection);
        }
        return documents;
    }

    // Simulate a slow data source
    private List<String> searchInDataSource(String userId, String connection) {
        List<String> documents = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            sleepSeconds(3);
            documents.add("doc " + i + " from " + connection + " for " + userId);
        }
        return documents;
    }

    private void sleepSeconds(int seconds) {
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(seconds);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}

It finishes for 27 seconds. I got a task to switch this process to the parallel. When I get the request I should create 3 threads (or another number) and run them in parallel. It can be look like here:
    @GetMapping("/search/{userId}")
    public List<String> searchDocuments(@PathVariable String userId) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        List<String> connections = getUserConnections(userId);
        List<String> documents = asyncDocuments(userId, connections);
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Time taken: " + (end - start) / 1000 + " seconds");
        return documents;
    }

    // This method is the one that takes a long time to execute
    public List<String> asyncDocuments(String userId, List<String> connections) {
        List<CompletableFuture<List<String>>> futures = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String connection : connections) {
            futures.add(CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> searchInDataSource(userId, connection)));
        }

        // Wait for all futures to complete
        CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0])).join();//block until all futures are completed
        //By tis point all futures are completed

        List<String> collectedResults = new ArrayList<>();
        for (CompletableFuture<List<String>> future : futures) {
            collectedResults.addAll(future.join()); //join() will return the result of the future without blocking
        }

        return collectedResults;
    }

And it tasks 9 seconds. In the real project I use my executor service in the CompletableFuture and it is not spring boot but a simple servlet.
QUESTION: Is this ok to spawn a set of threads from the servlet? Is there any better way to have that same result? The main concern is resources. I use a global thread pool, so there is a boundary, I have a timeout after that I need to return all documents that I had found at that point but anyway it looks wrong. I read in the Java concurrency in practice that is wrong (I don't remember the chapter), I saw some SO questions that it is not a good approach but I am looking for a good explanation, references to a book, article, etc and also, if somebody knows an alternative pattern/approach/architecture how to solve this task I would hear that and appreciate that.

When posting here, strip your code down to the bare minimum needed to demonstrate your issue.

You have posted too much code to digest easily. But from what I can discern, these points may help you.
Executor service
Use an executor service to manage your threads.
In modern Java, an ExecutorService is AutoCloseable. So you can conveniently use try-with-resources syntax to automatically close the executor service after its tasks complete.
try (
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.… ;
) {
    // Submit tasks.
}
// Flow of control blocks here until tasks are completed/cancelled.

Consider defining a separate class for your task, for simplicity and clarity. Implement either Runnable or Callable; in your case, Callable.
package work.basil.example.threading.bunch;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class TextRetriever implements Callable < List < String > >
{
    private final String userId;
    private final String connection;

    public TextRetriever ( final String userId , final String connection )
    {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.connection = connection;
    }

    @Override
    public List < String > call ( ) throws Exception
    {
        List < String > documents = new ArrayList <>( );
        // Simulate hitting a remote service multiple times to retrieve text.
        for ( int ordinal = 1 ; ordinal <= 3 ; ordinal++ )
        {
            int countSeconds = 3 ;
            Thread.sleep( Duration.ofSeconds( countSeconds ) );
            documents.add( "Doc # " + ordinal + " from " + connection + " for " + userId + " in thread " + Thread.currentThread().threadId() );
        }
        return List.copyOf( documents ); // Return unmodifiable list, as general good habit.
    }
}

Next we write an app to create dummy data, then instantiate a bunch a tasks, and finally submit them all to an executor service. We capture the returned collection of Future objects to track the tasks’ progress and result.
If your task involves code that blocks, such as making network calls to an external service, use virtual threads for optimal performance in Java 21+. In code below we use Executors utility class to get an implementation of ExecutorService that creates a new virtual thread for each task. To learn more about virtual threads, read the JEP, and watch presentations by Ron Pressler, Alan Bateman, and José Paumard.
package work.basil.example.threading.bunch;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class App
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        App app = new App( );
        app.demo( );
    }

    private void demo ( )
    {
        System.out.println( "INFO - Demo start. Wait several seconds. " + Instant.now( ) );

        List < String > userIds = IntStream.rangeClosed( 101 , 105 ).mapToObj( String :: valueOf ).toList( );
        List < String > connections = List.of( "Alpha" , "Beta" , "Gamma" , "Delta" , "Epsilon" );

        Collection < TextRetriever > tasks = new ArrayList <>( userIds.size( ) );
        for ( int index = 0 ; index < userIds.size( ) ; index++ )
        {
            TextRetriever task = new TextRetriever( userIds.get( index ) , connections.get( index ) );
            tasks.add( task );
        }

        List < Future < List < String > > > futures = List.of( );
        long start = System.nanoTime( );
        try (
                // ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor( ) ;
                ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor( ) ;
        )
        {
            try
            {
                futures = executorService.invokeAll( tasks );
            } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { throw new RuntimeException( e ); }
        }
        // Flow-of-control blocks here, until tasks are all completed/failed.
        Duration elapsed = Duration.ofNanos( System.nanoTime( ) - start );
        System.out.println( "INFO - " + tasks.size( ) + " tasks making 3 calls that each takes 3 took a total time elapsed of " + elapsed );
        for ( Future < List < String > > future : futures )
        {
            try
            {
                List < String > result = future.get( );
                System.out.println( "result = " + result );
            } catch ( InterruptedException e )
            {
                throw new RuntimeException( e );
            } catch ( ExecutionException e )
            {
                throw new RuntimeException( e );
            }
        }

        System.out.println( "INFO - Demo end. " + Instant.now( ) );
    }
}

This code works. Five tasks, each making three simulated network calls of three seconds each should take about 45 seconds without concurrency via Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor( ). Indeed, we see that result.
45 seconds
INFO - Demo start. Wait several seconds. 2024-07-16T19:20:54.326360Z
INFO - 5 tasks making 3 calls that each takes 3 took a total time elapsed of PT45.091023166S
result = [Doc # 1 from Alpha for 101 in thread 21, Doc # 2 from Alpha for 101 in thread 21, Doc # 3 from Alpha for 101 in thread 21]
result = [Doc # 1 from Beta for 102 in thread 21, Doc # 2 from Beta for 102 in thread 21, Doc # 3 from Beta for 102 in thread 21]
result = [Doc # 1 from Gamma for 103 in thread 21, Doc # 2 from Gamma for 103 in thread 21, Doc # 3 from Gamma for 103 in thread 21]
result = [Doc # 1 from Delta for 104 in thread 21, Doc # 2 from Delta for 104 in thread 21, Doc # 3 from Delta for 104 in thread 21]
result = [Doc # 1 from Epsilon for 105 in thread 21, Doc # 2 from Epsilon for 105 in thread 21, Doc # 3 from Epsilon for 105 in thread 21]
INFO - Demo end. 2024-07-16T19:21:39.430072Z

9 seconds
Now switch out the executor service for one that creates a new virtual thread for each task. Replace Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor() with Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor(). We see the elapsed time drop from 45 seconds to 9 seconds. On a machine with enough available cores, we would expect all five tasks to be running simultaneously. Each task is running 3 tasks for 3 seconds each, but all at the same time. So we should get around 9 seconds total.
Subtasks
You could squeeze even more performance by having each task create sub-tasks that are then submitted to yet another ExecutorService. Network calls are very slow. So spinning so many tasks makes sense, especially with the very “cheap” virtual threads that make little demands on CPU & memory.
Revamp our task code, to break out subtasks.
package work.basil.example.threading.bunch;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class TextRetriever implements Callable < List < String > >
{
    private final String userId;
    private final String connection;

    public TextRetriever ( final String userId , final String connection )
    {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.connection = connection;
    }

    @Override
    public List < String > call ( ) throws Exception
    {
        List < Future < String > > futures = new ArrayList <>( );
        // Simulate hitting a remote service multiple times to retrieve text.
        try (
                ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor( ) ;
        )
        {
            for ( int ordinal = 1 ; ordinal <= 3 ; ordinal++ )
            {
                SingleDocumentFetch subTask = new SingleDocumentFetch( ordinal , this.userId , this.connection );
                Future < String > future = executorService.submit( subTask );
                futures.add( future );
            }
        }
        // Flow-of-control blocks here until the submitted tasks are completed/cancelled.
        List < String > documents = new ArrayList <>( futures.size( ) );
        for ( Future < String > future : futures )
        {
            String document = future.get( );
            documents.add( document );
        }

        return List.copyOf( documents ); // Return unmodifiable list, as general good habit.
    }

    static class SingleDocumentFetch implements Callable < String >
    {
        private final int ordinal;
        private final String userId;
        private final String connection;

        public SingleDocumentFetch ( final int ordinal , final String userId , final String connection )
        {
            this.ordinal = ordinal;
            this.userId = userId;
            this.connection = connection;
        }

        @Override
        public String call ( ) throws Exception
        {
            int countSeconds = 3;
            try { Thread.sleep( Duration.ofSeconds( countSeconds ) ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { throw new RuntimeException( e ); }
            return ( "Doc # " + this.ordinal + " from " + this.connection + " for " + this.userId + " in thread " + Thread.currentThread( ).threadId( ) );
        }
    }
}

3 seconds
Now run that same App code. See our elapsed time drop again, down to a total of 3 seconds.
INFO - Demo start. Wait several seconds. 2024-07-16T19:51:48.612254Z
INFO - 5 tasks making 3 calls that each takes 3 took a total time elapsed of PT3.016917417S
result = [Doc # 1 from Alpha for 101 in thread 34, Doc # 2 from Alpha for 101 in thread 36, Doc # 3 from Alpha for 101 in thread 38]
result = [Doc # 1 from Beta for 102 in thread 45, Doc # 2 from Beta for 102 in thread 46, Doc # 3 from Beta for 102 in thread 47]
result = [Doc # 1 from Gamma for 103 in thread 40, Doc # 2 from Gamma for 103 in thread 48, Doc # 3 from Gamma for 103 in thread 49]
result = [Doc # 1 from Delta for 104 in thread 42, Doc # 2 from Delta for 104 in thread 51, Doc # 3 from Delta for 104 in thread 52]
result = [Doc # 1 from Epsilon for 105 in thread 35, Doc # 2 from Epsilon for 105 in thread 37, Doc # 3 from Epsilon for 105 in thread 39]
INFO - Demo end. 2024-07-16T19:51:51.637262Z

Okay in general?
Regarding having many threads, or having an executor service per request, you asked:

is it a good idea in general?

As is so common, the answer is "it depends".
If using platform threads, you likely need to limit their number. No way to name exactly that limit. But a couple guidelines:

Generally that number is fewer than the number of cores for CPU-bound tasks. Example: On a 12-core machine, maybe limit to 6 or 7.
For blocking tasks like yours, that limit is maybe a few multiples of the number of cores. Example: On a 12-code machine, maybe limit to 30.

Virtual threads changes that calculus radically. With virtual threads, we need not worry about a thread limit per se, even a million or more is reasonable. But we may need to throttle the number of concurrent tasks if the tasks’ own work is expensive in terms of memory, CPU, other resources.
Caveats with executor service
Be very careful that you gracefully shutdown your executor service(s), eventually, before your web app exits. Otherwise your background threads may continue indefinitely, like zombies ‍♂️.
Also be very careful to trap and handle exceptions and errors.
Jakarta Concurrency
The above should be done only if you are using a Servlet container with limited features, such as Apache Tomcat or Eclipse Jetty.
If instead you are using a more powerful Servlet container that implements Jakarta Concurrency, then you should not spin out your own threads & executor service. You should instead mark your tasks with annotations for execution in threads managed by the container.
Jakarta Concurrency is safer, as managed threads should eliminate the risk of the zombie problem mentioned above.
If your web app is doing anything more than the simplest of tasks in background threads, then consider moving to a Servlet container that supports Jakarta Concurrency. For example, Apache TomEE builds on top of Tomcat to add support for various Jakarta technologies including Jakarta Concurrency. You can choose from several other open-source and commercial products as well, such as Open Liberty, WebSphere, Glassfish, Payara, WildFly, JBoss, etc.
Any Servlet container product supporting Jakarta EE Web Profile 9.1 or later is required to support Jakarta Concurrency.
By the way, some containers may be evolving to use virtual threads. But I do not know the status of that for any particular products.
Spring
If you are using Spring, you may want to use its concurrency features. I do not use Spring, so I cannot assist further. But you will find many existing content on Stack Overflow.

Thank you for so detailed answer. As I said I use ExecutorService but it is global. Do you think that creating a new ExecutorService per request is a good idea? ExecutorService should strict amount of threads but if you create a new ExecutorService per request you will not control amount of threads - each new request will create 1 ExecutorService with N threads. Yes, in the real app there are separate classes implemented Runnable or Callable and it works but my question was a little bit different - is it a good idea in general? I mean threads creation from servlet (with or without executor)

It is impossible to use virtual threads in my project for now (java 11)

If you deploy to a machine with multiple cores, you should still see a time reduction by using platform threads from one of the other ExecutorService implementations  provided by Executors utility class. Use one with a limited number of threads, to not overwhelm your particular machine. Virtual threads are so “cheap” as to eliminate that issue. You can run even a million virtual threads simultaneously on conventional hardware.

Regarding new ExecutorService per request… Yes that makes sense when using virtual threads, as there is virtually no overhead. If backed by platform threads, there is an overhead to launching them. So in that case, in a high-volume deployment scenario, consider using an executor service backed by a thread pool of threads that get recycled. But beware of lingering ThreadLocal objects, if you use them. And remember: The best scenario is to use Jakarta Concurrency (or Spring) facilities rather than manage executor services yourself.

You asked: "is it a good idea in general?" — As is so common, the answer is "it depends". If using platform threads, you likely need to limit their number. Generally that number is fewer than the number of cores for CPU-bound tasks, and maybe a few multiples of the number of cores for blocking tasks (as in your situation). Virtual threads changes that calculus radically, where we need not worry about a thread limit per se, even a million or more is okay, though we may need to throttle the tasks if their own work is expensive in terms of memory or CPU or other resources.

Excellent answer. One problem worth mentioning is the common practice to pass along a context in web applications (e.g. user, session, etc.). That context is usually stored in a thread local and hence will not be available in manually managed threads.
